# Change JTextField from another Class Java/BlueJ

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, bluej

Im working on a project with JFrame (first time). I have some JTextFields and 1 JButton on the frame. So what I am trying to do is to edit text of my JTextField from another class. I'm entering 2 values in a JTextField and I want the outcome to be shown in another JTextField.

Whenever I press the Button I want one JTextField textfield9 to be changed into the value I calculated in my other class's method (in this case the totalHours() method in Module).

I've been trying a lot of examples I've found but none of them seems to worked for me T_T.

Here is te code I have problems with.

GUI Class:

```
private JButton button1;
private JTextField textfield5; // First value
private JTextField textfield7; // Second value
public JTextField textfield9;  // Outcome - I made it public because I would get an error of 'cannot find symbol setText()' in the Module Class (totalHours() method)

// So when I click on the Button I want the textfield9 to show the method (totalHours()) from the Module class
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            Module module = new Module();
            int text = module.totalHours();
            String textt = Integer.valueOf(text).toString();
            textfield9.setText(textt);
        }
    });
```

Module Class:

This is the outcome I want it to be shown in textfield9 whenever I click on the button on the frame

```
public int totalHours()
{
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(getHoursWeek());        // getter from GUI Class - textfield5
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(getTotalWeeksCourse()); // getter from GUI Class - textfield7
    int num3 = num1 * num2;
    gui.textfield9.setText(Integer.toString(num3));
    return num3;
}
```

I dont know why, but nothing is showing up in textfield9, instead it is opening another JFrame with 2 Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at Module.totalHours(Module.java:49)
at GUI$1.actionPerformed(GUI.java:67)
```

It's these 2 lines:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(getHoursWeek()); // Module Class totalHours() method
int text = module.totalHours();  // GUI Class button1 actionlistener
```

Here is the full code of both Classes. Deleting unnecessary lines.

GUI Class:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame 
{
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JButton button1;
    private JLabel label5;
    private JLabel label7;
    private JLabel label9;
    private JTextField textfield5;
    private JTextField textfield7;
    public JTextField textfield9;

//Constructor 
public GUI()
{        
    setTitle("GUI");
    setSize(468,400);

    //pane with null layout
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(null);
    contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(468,400));
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(192,192,192));

    button1 = new JButton();
    button1.setBounds(181,332,127,44);
    button1.setText("Invoer");

    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            Module module = new Module();
            int text = module.totalHours();
            String textt = Integer.valueOf(text).toString();
            textfield9.setText(textt);
        }
    });

    label5 = new JLabel();
    label5.setBounds(5,115,94,31);
    label5.setText("Module Nummer");

    label7 = new JLabel();
    label7.setBounds(274,14,156,33);
    label7.setText("Per module");

    label9 = new JLabel();
    label9.setBounds(276,57,90,35);
    label9.setText("Totaal uren");

    textfield5 = new JTextField();
    textfield5.setBounds(120,225,90,35);

    textfield7 = new JTextField();
    textfield7.setBounds(120,280,90,35);

    textfield9 = new JTextField();
    textfield9.setBounds(361,57,90,35);

    //adding components to contentPane panel
    contentPane.add(button1);
    contentPane.add(label5);
    contentPane.add(label7);
    contentPane.add(label8);
    contentPane.add(label9);
    contentPane.add(textfield5);
    contentPane.add(textfield7);
    contentPane.add(textfield9);

    //adding panel to JFrame and seting of window position and close operation
    getContentPane().add(contentPane);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    //initGUI();
}

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    System.setProperty("swing.defaultlaf", "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() 
        {
            new GUI();
        }
    });
}

public String getTextfield1()
{
    String txtfield1 = textfield1.getText();
    return txtfield1;
}

public String getTextfield2()
{
    String txtfield2 = textfield2.getText();
    return txtfield2;
}

public String getTextfield3()
{
    String txtfield3 = textfield3.getText();
    return txtfield3;
}

public String getTextfield4()
{
    String txtfield4 = textfield4.getText();    
    return txtfield4;
}

public String getTextfield5()
{
    String txtfield5 = textfield5.getText();
    return txtfield5;
}

public String getTextfield7()
{
    String txtfield7 = textfield7.getText();
    return txtfield7;
}

public String getTextfield9()
{
    String txtfield9 = textfield9.getText();
    return txtfield9;
}
}
```

Module Class:

```
public class Module
{
private GUI gui;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Module
 */
public Module()
{
    gui = new GUI();
}

public String getCourseName()
{
    return gui.getTextfield1();
}

public String getSchoolDays()
{
    return gui.getTextfield2();
}

public String getModuleNumber()
{
    return gui.getTextfield3();
}

public String getWeekNumber()
{
    return gui.getTextfield4();
}

public String getHoursWeek()
{
    return gui.getTextfield5();
}

public String getTotalWeeksCourse()
{
    return gui.getTextfield7();
}

public int totalHours()
{
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(getHoursWeek());    
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(getTotalWeeksCourse());
    int num3 = num1 * num2;
    gui.textfield9.setText(Integer.toString(num3));
    return num3;
}
}
```

Sorry if it's hard to understand what I'm trying to say, never been good in explaining things. Could anyone help me out with this!?

Comment: Have you tried setting the text in the original class first? I mean, not trying to set text from another class, but can you change it from the original class first? If so, and it works, create a public method in the original class that sets the text, and then use that mathod in the second class

Comment: I would offer more help but, this is a code dump, it's really difficult to read or understand - Use this when asking questions https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&ei=_Cu1VIeBGM-KNv_ogcgD&usg=AFQjCNEkKReghNZHBJSaky_hwPskMmG0ww&sig2=BhiNbmc9IjesvP1y5JKaMA&bvm=bv.83339334,d.eXY

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper settext from the GUI does indeed work, but I'm not sure what you're meaning with the public method one.

Comment: You have class 1 and class 2, class 1 changes text just fine, class 2 does not, correct?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper Yes, indeed. If I try to change the text within the GUI class itself, it does work (with the actionlisteren button).

Comment: Then make a method in class 1 that does just that, changes the text, make it a public method, and then, call that method in class 2. I wanted to mention pack() or repaint(), but that may make things more difficult for you. The plain and simple way is this, if it works on c1, but not c2, make a method of it in c1, and then call it from c2

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper So I made a method of it in GUI class (public void), called it in the Module class with a public void, but I am still getting the error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: nevermind, i see it now, Ok, that's an issue with your data coming in. The exception is that, it can't parse the string for whatever reason. Do me a favor, call System.out.println() and in the parantheses, print out the data you are trying to parse

Comment: Lol, my bad mate, totally different problem I was trying to solve for ya

Comment: I have this in the GUI Class: public void invoer(). Module Class: public void total(){gui.invoer();}. The program runs. but when I try to get the value in the textfield9 after clicking the button, it opens another JFrame(no idea why) and the error says: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Right, I reedited my post, call System.out.println() before that line where you parse, and in the parantheses, put in the data that you are trying to parse - namely, the gethours

Comment: Infinite loop of opening new JFrame windows. Is there no other way to do the calculation in the second class and settext in the GUI class?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper is it possible for you give an example with settext from another class?

Comment: im confused, what do you mean by infinite loops? Did it start spitting infinite loops of new JFrames after you typed in that System.out.println?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper Yes, it is opening infinite new JFrames after that line. Dont know why it opens op a new JFrame anyway.

Comment: And if you remove that line it stops doing infinite loops?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper Yes, it does. Now it opens only 1 more JFrame after the button click.

Comment: ???? The hell? Ok, post all the code, im running this myself.... now im just curious

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper my full code is available above. Last 2 code block. I dont have any imports with it.

Comment: got it, give me a sec, ill reply once i get it figured out

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper Thanks. I think you should add some imports, coz I ddint incluse them.

Comment: Oops - sorry - didn't see the long conversation going on while drafting answer.  Sorry @DreadHeadedDeveloper - I think you've got to a similar point to me.

Comment: Dont apologize, you solved the answer first, and quite well too. Need more ppl like you on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are creating a new Module object within your ActionListener inner class each time you click the button, which in turn creates a new GUI object and so on...  You've also got a nasty potential loop - if you move the module out of the ActionListener, it will create a new GUI, which will create a new Module, create a new GUI and so on...

There are a few issues - I'll address them one by one:

### Cyclical reference

Don't create a new GUI for each Module and a new Module for each GUI.  Instead - have a field for the reference to the GUI and a setGUI() method in the Module:

```
public class Module
{
    private GUI gui;

    public void setGUI(GUI myGUI)
    {
        this.gui = myGUI;
    }
 ... // rest of Module class
```

call this from the GUI constructor i.e.

```
module.setGUI(this);
```

### Creating Module objects in the ActionListener

Then problem is with this block of code:

```
   button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        Module module = new Module();
        int text = module.totalHours();
        String textt = Integer.valueOf(text).toString();
        textfield9.setText(textt);
    }
});
```

In particular - this line:

```
Module module = new Module();
```

You need a single instance of the Module object referenced from your GUI object.  Then, you read the totalHours from that same object every time.  There are a few different options for how you do this - I'll propose one:

1. Have module as a field in your GUI class
2. Make the GUI class implement ActionListener
3. add your actionPerformed method to the GUI class:

   `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        int text = module.totalHours();
        String textt = Integer.valueOf(text).toString();
        textfield9.setText(textt);
    }`
4. replace your current code for adding the action listener with  `button1.addActionListener(this);`

### Exception on receiving nothing from the totalHours() method

You see

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

If you look down the stack trace - you find something like:

```
at Module.totalHours(Module.java:49)
```

When you look at your totalHours() method, it is reading the GUI textfields and trying to parse them into integers.  They are empty (unless you've typed something into them), so parseInt is trying to create an integer from an empty string ("").  You need to add some error checking to that method.

Comment: literally started writing out the same solution.... Oh well, well worded and to the point, +1

Comment: @JRichardSnape Thanks you for the time looking into my code, I rlly appreciate it. I implemented your answer, atleast I tried. I added the setGUI() method to the Module class and module.setGUI(this); to the GUI constructor. I moved the 'Module module = new Module();' to the fields of the GUI, but now I am getting a 'StackOverFlow sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig' error whenever I try to run the program. It starts at the GUI constructor. I tried deleting 'GUI gui = new GUI();' from the Module class but then the setGUI() wouldnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper Thank you too for the time! But I still got some errors, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to say that you needed to remove `GUI gui = new GUI();` from the Module class.  You need to replace it with `GUI gui;` - i.e. you still have a field in the Module that contains the GUI reference, but you don't initialise it every time the Module object is instantiated.  I'll edit the answer.